# In QTP how to store string in one array and number in another array

Tags: qtp

In QTP take the 10 inputs from user, if passed input is string store it in one array and if it is number then store it in another array

Comment: Can somebody help me? Actually I am trying this with ReDim Preserve

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. Have you tried any code you can post, so that users can suggest improvements? See [ask] for improving the format of your question.

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted!

Answer (score 0):

```
size_of_num=0
size_of_nonnum=0
Dim Num()
Dim Nonnum()
For i=1 to 10
val = InputBox ("Enter a number or a string", "User Input")
msgbox val
If IsNumeric(val) Then
    msgbox "numeric"
    Redim Preserve Num(size_of_num)
    Num(size_of_num) = val
    msgbox "Num("& size_of_num &") -->" & Num(size_of_num)
    size_of_num=size_of_num+1
else
    msgbox "string"
    Redim Preserve Nonnum(size_of_nonnum)
    Nonnum(size_of_nonnum) = val
    msgbox "Nonnum("& size_of_nonnum &") -->" & Nonnum(size_of_nonnum)
    size_of_nonnum=size_of_nonnum+1
End If
Next
```

Try this